# How do I install Pinegrow?

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded the `PinegrowLinux64.2.51.zip` file. Here is the content. What do I do from this point on?

[image]

## Update

I have tried the following and the outcome is seen as:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the contents of the archive (preferably to `/opt`):

```
sudo unzip PinegrowLinux64.2.51.zip -d /opt/pinegrow
```

Now create a symbolic link for easier running:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/pinegrow/Pinegrow\ Web\ Designer /usr/local/bin/pinegrow
```

You can now run the program with:

```
pinegrow
```

If you want to create an icon (aka a "launcher") see this question: [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) (scroll down a bit if you want a GUI answer).

Comment: Hey there. Can you check the update I added on the question?

Comment: @SarpSTA It looks like your system is running a 32 bit install of Ubuntu. Pinegrow is 64 bit, and they don't provide 32bit binaries. You have three options here: If you have a 64bit CPU you can reinstall Ubuntu as 64bit or install a 64bit Ubuntu in Virtualbox/VMWare or bug the pinegrow folks to build a 32bit binary.

Comment: Weird. I could've sworn I installed 64 bit but it really is 32 bit. I'll take my chance with Windows. Thank you!